# Android - Custom Adapter Item Info

Tags: android, adapter

I have this custom adapter, I added a new item like this;

```
       card = new CardModel(name, email, image1);
          card.setOnClickListener(new CardModel.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnClickListener() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I am pressing the card");
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), email.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    card.setOnCardDimissedListener(new CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLike() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I dislike the card");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDislike() {
                            Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I like the card");
                            new sendNewYay().execute(sharedToken, name);
                        }
                    });


                    adapter.add(card);
                    mCardContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
```

At the `onDislike` method, I need to get item name.

in this line :

```
new sendNewYay().execute(sharedToken, name);
```

I send the item name, But it doesn't work.

1. How can I get the item name, in this method?
2. I have two buttons, one of them for `onLike` method, another one for `onDislike` Method. How can I triggered this two method with my button?

Answer (score 1):

I would change how you define the methods in the `CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener` interface like so:

```
public interface OnCardDimissedListener {
    void onLike(CardModel card);
    void onDislike(CardModel card);
}
```

Whatever is calling these methods should pass the `CardModel` instance on which the action was performed. Then your listener can get the name like this:

```
new CardModel.OnCardDimissedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLike(CardModel card) {
        Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I dislike the card");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDislike(CardModel card) {
        Log.i("Swipeable Cards", "I like the card");
        new sendNewYay().execute(sharedToken, card.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Karakuri. I did what you sad, But I m getting error in my cardcontainer.java like this : method onDislike in interface OnCardDimissedListener cannot be applied to given types;
required: CardModel 
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: and this is my cardcontainer.java https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards/blob/master/AndTinder/src/main/java/com/andtinder/view/CardContainer.java

Comment: in the cardcontainer.java line of 458 I change it like this : cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().onDislike(cardModel); But I cant get the item name..

Comment: Add a `getName()` method to your CardModel.

Comment: its already in cardModel constructor. Like this; 
 public CardModel(String title, String description, String image) {
  this.title = title;
  this.description = description;
  this.image = image;
 }

Comment: and in ondislike method I call it like this :   new sendNewYay().execute(sharedToken, card.getTitle());

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I cant get the item info. Its just giving the last item info. Because in the cardcontainer.java they write like this :  CardModel cardModel = (CardModel)getAdapter().getItem(0); its always turning item 0. check at the line 351 and 449 please, https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards/blob/master/AndTinder/src/main/java/com/andtinder/view/CardContainer.java

Comment: This is not a library i'm familiar with. You should contact the author if you think there's a problem with this code.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think Karakuri is right.
2. You can implement the click event in your custom adapter.

Like this: (I just use BaseAdapter as an example)

```
class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<CardModel> list;

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(arg0);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        Button btn1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //  onLike method
            }
        });
        Button btn2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //  onDislike Method and catch the name value
                String name = list.get(position).getName;
            }
        });
        return (row);
    }
}
```

And if you want to catch the onClick events in the main activity, you can transfer the CardModelListener into custom adapter. So once user click the button, events will be caught in the main activity.

Like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    class CardModelListener implements CardModeInterface {

        @Override
        public void onLike(CardModel card) {
            //onLike method
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisLike(CardModel card) {
            //onLike method
        }

    }

    interface CardModeInterface {
        onLike(CardModel card);
        onDisLike(CardModel card);
    }

}
```

And transfer the instance of CardModelListener to Custom Adapter:

```
class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private CardModelListener listener;

    public Adapter(CardModelListener onClickListener) {
        this.listener = onClickListener;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(arg0);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        Button btn1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onLike(list.get(position);
            }
        });

        return (row);
    }
}
```

I think this can resolve your first question. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Actually I saw some solution at this way. But I cant implement. I m trying but I cant. I m using this framework but I dont know how Can I implement your code. https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards/blob/master/AndTinder/src/main/java/com/andtinder/view/CardContainer.java